# got error when dump object to json

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn

Hi guys I want ask about `json.dump`

I use scikit to tune some method with parameters and I want dump it to json, but I got some error here :
I have parameter with method KNN:

```
KNeighborsClassifier(algorithm=u'auto', leaf_size=30, metric=u'manhattan',
metric_params=None, n_jobs=-1, n_neighbors=300, p=2,
     weights=u'distance')
```

But got error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "jamu.py", line 1018, in <module>
    main(argv)
  File "jamu.py", line 863, in main
    json.dumps(meta_clf, f)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 250, in d
    sort_keys=sort_keys, **kw).encode(obj)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\encoder.py", line 207, in en
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\encoder.py", line 270, in it
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\encoder.py", line 184, in de
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable"
TypeError: KNeighborsClassifier(algorithm=u'auto', leaf_s
tan',
       metric_params=None, n_jobs=-1, n_neighbors=300
       weights=u'distance') is not JSON serializable
```

Is anything wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i use this way:

```
meta_clf = KNeighborsClassifier(algorithm=u'auto', leaf_size=30,     metric=u'manhattan',
metric_params=None, n_jobs=-1, n_neighbors=300, p=2,
 weights=u'distance')


def print_to_json(meta_clf):
meta_clf_str = str(meta_clf)
meta_clf_str = meta_clf_str[meta_clf_str.index("(") + 1:meta_clf_str.rindex(")")]
meta_clf_str = meta_clf_str.replace('\n           ', '')
meta_clf_str = meta_clf_str.replace(' ', '')
meta_clf_str = meta_clf_str.replace('=u\'', '=\'')
meta_clf_str = meta_clf_str.replace('\'', '')
meta_clf_str_list = meta_clf_str.split(',')
meta_clf_str_list_len = len(meta_clf_str_list)
meta_clf_str_lists = []
params = {}

for x in meta_clf_str_list:
    meta_clf_str_list = x.split('=')
    if meta_clf_str_list[1].isdigit() == True:
        meta_clf_str_list[1] = int(meta_clf_str_list[1])
    meta_clf_str_lists.append(meta_clf_str_list)
    params[meta_clf_str_list[0]] = meta_clf_str_list[1]
return params
```

it's enough for me.
thanks for the asnwer thomas, i appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

It is what it says on the tin, `KNeighborsClassifier` cannot be serialised with `json`.

You'll have to use a different way to serialise a model. For example you can use `joblib`:

```
from sklearn.external import joblib

# Suppose your KNeighborsClassifier model is called knn
joblib.dump(knn, 'some/kind/of/path/knn.joblib')
```

Loading a model is equally simple:

```
knn = joblib.load('some/kind/of/path/knn.joblib')
```

Check the [joblib docs](https://pythonhosted.org/joblib/) for what else it is good for.

Comment: it's work but it produce '.NPY' file extension, i want dump it to json, is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Any reason why you desperately want it to be `json`? Its not an appropriate choice for what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: i have dump it to pickle file, but i want it to visible so i can know what estimator i use to tuning my dataset.

Comment: can you not encode that information in your filename or path? otherwise you might overwhelm yourself with bookkeeping when serialising or de-serialising a model